# How to handle Race Condition in Cassandra?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, race-condition, spring-data-cassandra

I am developing a simple Spring Boot microservice with Cassandra db.

The main entity in my server in `Subscription` class below:

```
public final class Subscription {

    private String id;

    private String firstUser;

    private String secondUser;

    private String firstUserStatus;

    private String secondUserStatus;

}
```

My repository consumes Subscription object and persists it.
But before persisting, I should check for some constraints and the main is that there mustn't be another subscription with the same `firstUser` and `secondUser`.
The case when it can fail is pretty simple:

1. one subscription is going to be persisted
2. table is being verified for the existence of another subscription with
   the same users
3. another subscription with the same users could be persisted now and
   make the previous verification stale
4. subscription is being persisted.

What is the proper way to resolve it?

Worth mentioning: the order of users doesn't matter. If subscription with users "1" and "2" is going to be persisted no other subscription with users "1" and "2" or "2" and "1" must exist.

UPD: considering @bhspencer answer, I could propose another case (I need also force statuses to be consistent):

1. one subscription is going to be persisted with `firstUserStatus="ISSUED"` and `secondUserStatus="WAITING_ACTION"`
2. table is being verified for the existence of another subscription with the same users
3. another subscription with the same id (users) and `firstUserStatus="WAITING_ACTION"` and `secondUserStatus="ISSUED"` could be persisted now and make the previous verification stale
4. initial subscription is being persisted and overrides the already existed one -> `secondUserStatus="ISSUED"` is lost

Comment: What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: the primary key is id, of course

Answer (score 2):

Make the id of the object a concatenation of firstUser + secondUser. Make id the primary key that will ensure your subscriptions are unique.

Because of your ordering requirement you should sort the firstUser and secondUser first and concatenate them in sort order. Doing this means generateId("1", "2") and generateId("2". "1") would both generate the same id "1-2".

```
public String generateId(String firstUser, String secondUser) {
  List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
  ids.add(firstUser);
  ids.add(secondUser);
  Collections.sort(ids);
  String result = ids.get(0) + "-" + ids.get(1);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this option suits only for the specific case and isn't a general race condition solution

Comment: There isn't going to be a general solution.

Comment: You could try the above example in combination with a lightweight transaction "IF NOT EXISTS" on your other fields https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html